# Setting metadata using Azure C++ SDK

Tags: c++, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to set metadata on a file in Azure blob storage using the following code:

```
bool AzureUploader::uploadFile(const boost::filesystem::path& filePath)
{
    auto leaf = filePath.filename();
    azure::storage::cloud_blob_container container =
        blob_client.get_container_reference(U("my_container"));
    container.create_if_not_exists();
    azure::storage::cloud_block_blob blockBlob =
        container.get_block_blob_reference(leaf.wstring());
    auto filepathStr = filePath.wstring();
    blockBlob.upload_from_file(filepathStr);
    blockBlob.download_attributes();
    azure::storage::cloud_metadata md = blockBlob.metadata();
    md[U("_timestamp")] = U("today");
    blockBlob.upload_metadata();
}
```

Yet when I look at the file in Azure Storage Explorer there is no metadata set. I've looked about a bit and this does seem to be the way to set metadata, but for whatever reason it's not working.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this tearing their hair out, the answer is you need to attain a *reference* to `cloud_metadata` if you're updating it:

```
azure::storage::cloud_metadata& md = blockBlob.metadata();
```

or simply

```
auto& md = blockBlob.metadata();
```

Then it works as expected!